# How do I turn off GIT_TRACE?

Tags: git

I suddenly started receiving permission denied errors when trying to `fetch` from our git server. According to [this document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASHKB/Git+Operations+Fail+-+Permission+denied+-+publickey), I used the `GIT_TRACE_PACKET` AND `GIT_TRACE` commands. We found the problem and fixed it, but now every git command I run is getting traced. Can someone tell me how to turn this function off?

Comment: Stop exporting non-zero values for ``GIT_TRACE_PACKET`` and ``GIT_TRACE``.  Wherever you turned them on to enable tracing: go back there and take them out.

Comment: I don't even know what that means. I did exactly what the article said to do, which is `export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1, export GIT_PACKET=1` in my bash window. How do I "go back there" and take them out?

Comment: `GIT_TRACE_PACKET` and `GIT_PACKET` aren't commands, they are environment variables. Just reset them to 0 to disable the behavior `export VARIABLE=0`

Comment: @ZachThacker `GIT_PACKET` isn't even an environment variable, it's a typo. If I was working with `GIT_TRACE_PACKET` and `GIT_TRACE`, I'd probably end up using the wrong name to refer to `GIT_TRACE` as well!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As everyone said in comments, those are not actually commands.  There is a command involved (`export`) but it's a *shell* (`bash` in your case, although there are other shells) command, not a *git* command.  It changes the set of environment-variables that the shell provides to other commands.

So, you just need to un-do the thing you did in bash, with another bash command.

You can use [SirBraneDamuj's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487190/how-do-i-turn-off-git-trace#comment32433314_21487190):

```
export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=0 GIT_TRACE=0
```

This keeps those variables in the environment but changes their value.  Or, you can:

```
unset GIT_TRACE_PACKET GIT_TRACE
```

which removes those two names from the set of environment variables entirely.  The effect on git will be the same either way.  (For some other commands, and some other variables, there's sometimes a difference between "set to 0 or to empty-string" vs "not set at all", so it's worth remembering both methods.)

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware that they were shell commands, not git ones. But I didn't know how to undo them. `unset` worked.

Answer (score 2):

While fixing a connection and permissions issue with Git, HTTPS, SSH, and a corporate proxy I ended up with a ton of leftover debug and verbose options and no real clear reason why these options were persisting.

If you end up in my position, you'll want to completely clean house:

- `GIT_TRACE`, `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE` need to be unset or set to zero to turn off logging from Git or Git's usage of cURL
- Custom `ssh` commands stored in `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`, `GIT_SSH` might be hiding a `-v` or `--verbose` that need to be cleared out
- Set the LogLevel back to `INFO` in `~/.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` for the domain(s) you're pulling against
- Unset or remove the verbose options from the `core.sshcommand` in your `gitconfig`, you can use `git config --list --show-origin` to see *all* of your configurations and which files they live in
- While you're looking at your `gitconfig`, check that your aliases aren't hiding verbose options